# will strictly defining class variables in php 7.4 be faster?

Tags: php, optimization, php-7.4

in php 7.4, i can now define class property types: So instead of:

```
class A{
  /** @var string */
  protected $string;
}
```

i can now do:

```
class A{
  protected string $string;
}
```

so, is it worthwhile to do this? ie, is it worth recoding my code base to use this feature?

is there a performance boost?

Comment: That's more about data integrity, not performance. It's so you can be sure that a property always have a specific type and you won't need to type check them, if the type is crucial. If there are any performance gains/losses, they will most likely be negligible.

Comment: thanks, i get that, i just wondered if the compiler had optimisations to make the code run faster, functionally my IDE semantically understands that $string is a string so it warns me if i try something silly like $string = $string + 1;  etc...

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typed_properties_v2 - _"The main takeaway is that typed properties have an impact on performance even if they are not used. For applications, the impact is around 1-2%. We expect that performance will be improved prior to landing, but at least some impact is probably not avoidable."_

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks, if you make that an answer i can accept it. Cheers.

Comment: From the functionality standpoint, the only difference is that typed properties add extra steps: type checks and (depending on strict_types settings) a cast to target type or a fatal error). Obviously, doing n+1 things will be always slower than doing n things. Type info could certainly be leveraged to add optimisations at Zend engine level (no idea about that) but, in the end, you need to benchmark in your actual server to figure out. Still, if having a typed property saves additional checks and casts in your userland code it might be faster in the end.

Comment: Regarding my last point, I easily found a snippet where typed properties make faster code in my PC (7.4.5 Win64) because I save a check, but you just need to see the ([3v4l.org fiddle](https://3v4l.org/Ehh5e)) to see results aren't consistent across different environments.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks, very interesting... so it will be faster in PHP8, but for now with php 7.4 it isn't worth doing. Nearly all of my code base has protected class parameters, so i do the type checking on getters and setters anyway. when i upgraded from 7.2 to 7.4 the IDE gave me the option to use typed parameters and i just wondering if it was refactoring my code. seems at this stage from my point of view there is no point.

Comment: Please note that my typed/untyped examples use different code (because that's what I was trying to illustrate) and results are basically inconsistent. You'd need to benchmark *your* code in *your* server to reach conclusions that are relevant to you. I honestly think it isn't worth it and I agree with Magnus: use the design that makes your code more reliable or easy to maintain; performance trade-offs are likely to be negligible.

Comment: Any performance gains are going to be negligible. You’re better off looking at other topics that will yield larger performance gains if this is a concern, and not whether class properties are strongly typed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about performance, typed properties are meant to enforce type contracts in your code. It's difficult to say if there is any performance difference, whether positive or negative, but the performance should not be the reason why you should specify types.

You already use PHPDoc comments, which means that it is important for you to know what type the property should be, but PHPDoc block does not enforce it. This code is perfectly valid:

```
<?php

class A {
    /** @var int */
    public $number;
}

$a = new A();
$a->number = 'a';
echo $a->number;
```

With typed properties, you tell PHP runtime to check the type before assignment or usage. PHP will not allow type mismatch. This code will throw an error:

```
<?php

class A {
    public int $number;
}

$a = new A();
$a->number = 'a';
echo $a->number;
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign string to property A::$int of type int